# jquery.jmslideshow.js how to stop then it reaches the end

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slideshow, impress.js

Trying to use beautiful [jquery.jmslideshow.js](https://github.com/shama/jmpress.js) from [codrops tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/05/slideshow-with-jmpress-js/) on my website, but not familiar with jquery.

One question, - how I can stop jmpress slider with autoplay option enabled on last slide? once it reaches the final slide.

Hope this is a simple question for one of you and good jquery howto for me. If anyone could help it would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for reply, What i tried? I registered on stackoveflow, man) I have searched all around with no luck, think I have to deeper dive in js,English, cause problem defined, no search result, sample code or ide reference founded):

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem just like you, and this is how I made it work.

Instead of `jmpress.min.js`, import `impress.js` for readability. Then search for the word "circular". This is the part that actually repeats it.

Look for this piece:

```
do {
    var item = step.near( stepSelector, prev );

    if (item.length === 0 || item.closest(jmpress).length === 0) {
        console.log(item);
    }

    if (!item.length) {
        return false;
    }

    step = item;

} while( step.data("stepData").exclude );

return step;
```

Now remove anything that is written in the first if, and you are good to go. The slideshow now stops at the end.